# Continuity and Derivatives at $x=1$

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Given $f(x) = [x] +\sqrt{\{x\}}$, where $[.],\{.\}$ denote greatest integer and fractional part function.
What can we say about continuity and derivaties at $x=1$?

I think it is continuous as left hand limit and right hand limits are same.
How to check for derivatives?

Comment: `How to check for derivatives?` Take the same `left hand limit and right hand limits` idea one step farther.

Comment: @dxiv it comes to be $lim_{h->0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{h}}$ So it doesn't exist right?

Comment: Right, it's not differentiable at $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the continuity of $f$, the function is continuous.

To study the differentiability of $f$ around $1$, you have to evaluate the following limit:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$$

Let $h$ be a small positive number (less than $1$), then 
$$\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=\frac{[1+h]+\sqrt{\{1+h\}}-1}{h}=\frac{\sqrt{h}}{h}=\frac{\sqrt{0+h}-\sqrt{0}}{h}$$
which is the derivative of the square root function at $0$ when $h\to 0^+$ (it goes to infinity).

The right-hand limit of the difference quotient of $f$ goes to infinity so the function is not differentiable at $1$.

Comment: The right hand derivative=lim 1/h^(1/2) and left hand derivative= lim (1-h)^(1/2)/h for h tends to 0. You did a mistake.

Comment: One may say both tend to infinity.

Comment: The function $f$ is said to be differentiable if the quotient converges to a real number when $h\to 0$. Infinity is not a real number so the derivative of $f$ is not defined at $1$.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I wanted to say that the right hand limit and and left hand limits are infinity, which implies it is non derivable. U said, only right hand limit does not exists. Thats a mistake.

Comment: Sorry left hand limit is-1/2. I did a mistake.

Comment: @Suprabha  You mean +1/2. Because it is the left hand limit as h tends to 0 from + of $\frac{\sqrt{\{1-h\}} - \sqrt{1}}{h}$

Comment: No its -1/2 lim. of (\sqrt{1-h}-1)÷h

Comment: @Shailesh sorry u are correct. I did a mistake in taking sign of h.

Comment: @Suprabha  I think you can write a more complete answer. I'll definitely up-vote it. (Though it is sufficient to show what T, Haddad did)

Comment: @Suprabha I think saying that the right-hand limit of the difference quotient is not a real number is enough to prove that the function is not differentiable at $1$.

Comment: @Shailesh I admit T Haddad's answer is correct. I misunderstood a part"which is the derivative of the square root function at $0$ when $h\to 0$ (it goes to infinity)."

Comment: It should be 0+

Comment: @Suprabha You are right, I edited it so it becomes $h\to 0^+$. Thank you!

Comment: Always welcome.